# Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with int while filling data into data set

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table-valued parameter like this

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.Loc AS TABLE(Lo integer);
```

My stored procedure looks like this:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary]  
                        @startDate datetime,  
                        @endDate datetime,
                        @locations dbo.Loc readonly
              ..........................
              ...........................
WHERE     (Transaction_tbl.dtime BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate) 
AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (select Lo from @locations))
```

I have a listbox that contains multiple items. I can select multiple items from my listbox. How can I pass multiple Locationid to my stored procedure?

```vb
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
Dim dtlist As New DataTable()
Dim locid As Integer
If cnt > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To cnt - 1
        dtlist.Columns.Add(locid, GetType(Integer))
        Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
        locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
        dtlist.Rows.Add(locid)
    Next
End If

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("T_TransactionSummary", con.connect)
cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Dim tvp1 As SqlParameter = cmd23.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locations", dtlist)
tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
tvp1.TypeName = "dbo.Loc"
da.SelectCommand = cmd23
da.Fill(ds)
```

but i am getting error like this:

> Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with int

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `dtlist` should contain one column. You add many columns, and none of them is named `"Lo"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass multiple comma separated locationids. Use the methods suggested at http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Comment: so in this case where i have to make change..please advice me sir.